# Click-Once installation from Website not working

Tags: installation, clickonce

I have created a little winform project in Visual Studio 2019 and I have published it to a website.

I do get the index.html file where there is a download link to the setup.exe file.

But when I run the setup file I get an error, its like it cannot download the installation files from the website.

I did this a few years ago, but cannot remember how I got it to work.

Can any one help my, what do I need to get it to work?
Is it something on the webserver or something else?

Comment: Nobody tried this??
I would really like to know how to do it.

Comment: what error you get ?